# GitHub for Windows not showing repo owner

Tags: windows, github

This morning I woke up and all of my repos in GitHub for Windows had become unindexed. **Tools** > **Options** > **Scan for repositories** added all of them back to the list, but now only the name of the repos are being shown, instead of the usual owner\name:

[image: GitHub for Windows]

As you can see, my repos are diplaying as usual (with the owner name), as are repos that I've cloned after GitHub for Windows reset itself. Does anyone know what's going on? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have completely overlooked **Github For Windows Software**
what you want is already there you just need to click you account name name on the left side and you will get your repos in this form **username/repo** (however these repos are not local - you need to clone it into your hard-disk )

here is the attachment pic to make things more clear -
[image]

Comment: I get that - these are other people's repos that I've cloned using the `Clone in Desktop` button on GitHub.com. Please re-read my question